# Git not present in Android Studio version control

Tags: git, android-studio

I'm trying to push my Android Studio project to my Git repository, but I'm not able to see Git in my Android Studio's version control system. Is there a plugin to add Git into Android Studio or is there any other solutions?

Screenshot of my settings panel in Android Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution mate either:

1. You do not have the Git plugins which then go in into settings --> plugins --> search for git and download Git Integration and Github (why not).
2. You do have it and you are looking in the wrong place. Look at the top bar next to tools is VCS go in there and you should see Git options.

Let me know if you have issues. =)

[Git Intellij / Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abPau.png)